# Opacity issue in Internet Explorer and Opera

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, opacity

I've problem with opacity for IE8 and Opera9-10. My little JS adds a CSS class to a row (<tr>) when users click on it. This is the class:

```
.selected { 
    opacity: 0.5;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* IE7 */
}
```

Opacity is applied in Firefox and Google Chrome but not in IE and Opera.

Answer (score 4):

From the [IE Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx):

```
.selected { 
    opacity: 0.5;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);  /* IE7 */
}
```

If this still doesn't work, it's probably an issue with some inheritance and we'll need to see  some scirpt and markup or an online example.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you apply your class to a single TD in the table? Does that work any better? Another option would be to use a PNG with alpha-transparency as a background image for the TR and apply this via your class (but this wouldn't work in IE6).

Comment: Applying opacity on td (for i.e. on click) doesn't work for Opera and IE :)

Comment: I see that on Opera opacity support in JQuery is enabled on IE no